# How to update state from Phone view on WatchOS view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, watchos

I'm using a companion app to authorize a user with a 3rd party service. Once authorized, I update a `UserDefaults` variable to `true`. On the companion app side, the view updates correctly and shows that the user has been authenticated. However, on the watch OS side the view does not update. Would I need to use the Watch Connectivity API and send a message to the watch to update the state? Or is there a simple way?

Phone App

```
struct AuthenticationView: View {
    @State private var startingWebAuthenticationSession = false
    @AppStorage("authorized") private var authorized = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if !authorized {
                VStack {
                    Button("Connect", action: { self.startingWebAuthenticationSession = true })
                        .webAuthenticationSession(isPresented: $startingWebAuthenticationSession) {
                        WebAuthenticationSession(
                            url: URL(string: "https://service.com/oauth/authorize?scope=email%2Cread_stats&response_type=code&redirect_uri=watch%3A%2F%2Foauth-callback&client_id=\(clientId)")!,
                            callbackURLScheme: callbackURLScheme
                        ) { callbackURL, error in
                            guard error == nil, let successURL = callbackURL else {
                               return
                            }
                            
                            let oAuthCode = NSURLComponents(string: (successURL.absoluteString))?.queryItems?.filter({$0.name == "code"}).first
                            guard let authorizationCode = oAuthCode?.value else { return }
                            
                            let url = URL(string: "https://service.com/oauth/token")
                            var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
                            request.httpMethod = "POST"
                            
                            let params = "client_id=\(clientId)&client_secret=\(clientSecret)&grant_type=authorization_code&code=\(authorizationCode)&redirect_uri=\(callbackURLScheme)://oauth-callback";
                            
                            request.httpBody = params.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
                            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                                    if let error = error {
                                        print("Error took place \(error)")
                                        return
                                    }
                             
                                if let data = data, let response = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                                        let accessTokenResponse: AccessTokenResponse = try! JSONDecoder().decode(AccessTokenResponse.self, from: response.data(using: .utf8)!)
                                    
                                        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                                        authorized = true
                                        startingWebAuthenticationSession = false
                                        
                                        defaults.set(accessTokenResponse.access_token, forKey: DefaultsKeys.accessToken) //TODO: Store securely
                                        ConnectivityService.shared.send(authorized: true)
                                }
                            }
                            task.resume()
                        }
                        .prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession(false)
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                VStack {
                    Text("Authenticated!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

WatchOS

```
import SwiftUI

struct ConnectView: View {
    @ObservedObject var connectivityService: ConnectivityService
    
    var body: some View {
        if !$connectivityService.authorized.wrappedValue {
                VStack {
                    Text("Open the app on your primary device to connect.")
                }
            }
            else {
                //Some other view
            }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Trying with Watch Connectivity API but the issue I'm experiencing is that when I authenticate from the phone, it'll take some time for the `ConnectView` to update the `authorized` variable. I know Watch Connectivity API doesn't update right away but at minimum I'd need some way for the watch to pick up that a secret access token has been retrieved and it can transition to the next view; whether that's through a shared state variable, UserDefaults, or whatever other mechanism.

Here is the `ConnectivityService` class I'm using:

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import WatchConnectivity

final class ConnectivityService: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    static let shared = ConnectivityService()
    @Published var authorized: Bool = false
      
    override private init() {
        super.init()
        #if !os(watchOS)
            guard WCSession.isSupported() else {
                return
            }
        #endif
        WCSession.default.delegate = self
        WCSession.default.activate()
    }
    
    public func send(authorized: Bool, errorHandler: ((Error) -> Void)? = nil) {
        guard WCSession.default.activationState == .activated else {
            return
        }
        
        #if os(watchOS)
            guard WCSession.default.isCompanionAppInstalled else {
                return
            }
        #else
            guard WCSession.default.isWatchAppInstalled else {
                return
            }
        #endif
        
        let authorizationInfo: [String: Bool] = [
            DefaultsKeys.authorized: authorized
        ]
        
        WCSession.default.sendMessage(authorizationInfo, replyHandler: nil)
        WCSession.default.transferUserInfo(authorizationInfo)
    }
}


extension ConnectivityService: WCSessionDelegate {
    func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) { }
  
    func session(
      _ session: WCSession,
      didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String: Any] = [:]
    ) {
        let key = DefaultsKeys.authorized
        guard let authorized = userInfo[key] as? Bool else {
            return
        }
        
        self.authorized = authorized
    }
    
    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {
        self.authorized = true
    }

    #if os(iOS)
        func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) {
  
        }

        func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {
            WCSession.default.activate()
        }
    #endif
}
```

I tried doing these two lines but they have varying results:

`WCSession.default.sendMessage(authorizationInfo, replyHandler: nil)`
`WCSession.default.transferUserInfo(authorizationInfo)`

In the first line, XCode will say that no watch app could be found, even though I'm connected to both physical devices through XCode; launch phone first then watch. I believe the first one is immediate and the second is more of when the queue feels like it. Sometimes if I hard close the watch app, it'll pick up the state change in the `authorized` variable, sometimes it won't. Very frustrating inter-device communication.

`UserDefaults` doesn't pick up the access token value on the watch side. Maybe I have to use App Groups?

I do see this error on the Watch side:

`Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.`

So I thought to try and encapsulate the `self.authorized = authorized` call into something like:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
     self.authorized = authorized
}
```

But it didn't do anything as far as solving the immediate state change issue.

Comment: Yes you need to use Watch Connectivity! Let me know if you need help integrating it.

Comment: @NoeOnJupiter I did go the Watch Connectivity route by basically following this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/books/watchos-with-swiftui-by-tutorials/v1.0/chapters/4-watch-connectivity#toc-chapter-009-anchor-001 but the main issue right now is that after login on the phone device, I can't get the ConnectView screen to recognize that the authorized variable has changed. Do you know how I can set this up so that the view updated? Right now if I'm looking at both the phone and watch, the phone will instantly update, but the watch will stay there.

Comment: Try activating WCSession in the app delegate and extension delegate, you need to activate it as soon as you can!